# Twitter sharing screen issues in iOS 8

Tags: twitter, ios8

I found issue in twitter sharing screen disabling "Post" button after exceeding tweet limit and updating twitter limit count, if the characters are entered continuously after Sharing URL with "http://" prefix .But the count is incrementing after putting a white space after URL string. Do any one found any solution!

[image]

[image]

[image]